# Where do i put CoInitialize?

Tags: cherrypy

I am using ADO to connect to an SQL server from cherrypy.  Where should I be putting :

```
 pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

inside the __init__ or inside  the index method where the GET is performed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for COM info. You should call it once for every additional thread in the app, so I guess you either need to hack into the thread pool or have a thread-local flag if COM is initialized. Note that you should to call `CoUninitialize()` when thread terminates, and that is another problem that you cannot solve with the flag.

Or you could use a different DB lib like [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/)--it doesn't seem to use COM.

Comment: Thanks ill check out the thread -local flag.The weird thing is even when i take out all of my CoInitialize calls, the CherryPy server works fine and the data calls all work.  It seems like they aren't required.

Comment: Well, COM can do nasty things to your app if you don't do it correctly, so make sure you init it if your DB lib doesn't do that.